# broadcast shapes with stride

Tags: arrays, numpy, broadcast, stride

Now in numpy version 1.20.0 there is [`np.broadcast_shapes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_shapes.html) that will broadcast multiple shapes together, is there something similar but for broadcasting the strides - something like `np.broadcast_strides`?

Say I have two arrays `A` and `B` with the respective shapes `(1,)` and `(10,)`. I want to get the resulting strides from `out = np.broadcast_to(A, B.shape)` (which will be `out.strides = (0,)` in this case), but I don't care about doing the actual broadcast.

Comment: Hmm, realized that you can create a numpy array without allocating memory by doing ```np.empty(shape, dtype=[])```

Comment: That `dtype=[]` puzzled me until I saw your comment, and then realized it's a 0 field compound dtype.  But does that help?  Even if the shape is right, the strides will be (0,).

Comment: No, you're right. Even though broadcasting is basically just setting the stride to 0 for the broadcasted dimensions - it will not take into account which dimensions should *not* be broadcasted.